# ClickOnce check for updates even though it should not (under a particular circumstance)

Tags: c#, clickonce

I set my ClickOnce application to not checking for updates (Project Properties -> Publish -> Updates... -> "The application should check for updates" is unchecked) since I programmatically search for them and I leave the user the possibility to install them whenever he wants.

Now in the following scenario:

1. The application is launched
2. An update is found using the ClickOnce API
3. The application is not updated
4. The application is then closed
5. The next time the application is launched the ClickOnce window will prompt the user to install or skip the update.

How can this be avoided?

Interestingly, if then the user skip the installation, the next times the application will be launched the user will not be prompted any more, hence there should be something (in the manifest?) that tells ClickOnce to stop prompting.

Comment: When you say that you programmatically check, are you using the API CheckForDetailedUpdate?

Comment: I'm using CheckForUpdateAsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen something like this before. I think what is happening is that when the application is start up ClickOnce does not check for an update, which is what you have set. When you are run the application an update check is done programatically and an update is found and presumably a flag is set. The application is then shutdown with out updating but the flag is still set. The next time the application is started ClickOnce still does not check for an update BUT because there is a flag set that there is an update available it prompts the user to see if they want to grab the update. I am guessing that this is by design.

In regards to the second point where you skip the update you will not be prompted again until there is another update. This I believe is by design, if you want to go back and do the update you need to go to the ClickOnce install page for the application.

Ideally what you want to be able to do is do the same thing that happens when you skip using the ClickOnce dialog programatically using the Application Deployment API. I have had a quick look at the public methods available but I cannot see anything about skipping but maybe you can find something.

EDIT

Just had another look at the API. Are you calling CheckForUpdate() or CheckForDetailedUpdate() without a boolean parameter? If so the reason you are getting the prompt is as I said the update check is being stored:

> If CheckForUpdate discovers that an update is available, and the user
>   chooses not to install it, ClickOnce will prompt the user that an
>   update is available the next time the application is run. There is no
>   way to disable this prompting. (If the application is a required
>   update, ClickOnce will install it without prompting.)

Instead you want to call the method you are using with a boolean value of false, the boolean  flag determines if a dialog should be displayed to the user.

> persistUpdateCheckResult Type: System.Boolean
>   If false, the update will be applied silently and no dialog box will be displayed.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. The second point is not a problem for me, I simply would like to avoid any prompting in the first scenario

Comment: @Ganswer In your first example when an update is found does it start to download the update but the application shutdown before the update is complete or does it just find that there is an update available? Also is the update mandatory or not?

Comment: It just checks for update with CheckForUpdateAsync and it founds, but it does not download it. The update is not mandatory

Comment: @Ganswer I have updated my answer with what I think is going on. I think you need to see how you can do "Skip" programatically.

Comment: @Ganswer, think I have found the solution to your problem

Comment: You are right, by calling 'CheckForUpdate()' there is no way to avoid that prompting. While using 'CheckForDetailedUpdate(false)' the dialog can be avoided. I was not using it, since I wanted an async check for update, so my final solution is to use 'CheckForDetailedUpdate(false)' by starting a new Task.

Comment: Ganswer, would threads work for the same purpose? Making a separate process sounds expensive.

Comment: @Mathias Ganswer is using the Task Parallel Library from .net 4 which will start his process in another thread. If you are using .net 4 but have not looked at Task Parallel Library you should check it out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I see that the [ApplicationDeployment.CheckForUpdate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.checkforupdate.aspx) method [has an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646709.aspx) with `persistUpdateCheckResult` parameter.

However I am using the `CheckForUpdateAsync` which does not have any such overload. It appears to imply the persistence of the result as I am running into this issue.

I guess the solution is I write my own async call...